# How do I delete a row from a Microsoft Access table using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I've tried this code:

```
string sql = " DELETE FROM HotelCustomers WHERE [Room Number] =" +  textBox1.Text;
OleDbConnection My_Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= c:\\Users\\Documents\\HotelCustomersOld.mdb");

My_Connection.Open();

OleDbCommand My_Command = new OleDbCommand(sql, My_Connection);
My_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> Error: Data type mismatch in criteria expression, at the line:
>   My_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: What's the datatype of [Room Number]?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but this looks like a _classic_ example of a [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) vulnerability.

Comment: You are begging for a SQL injection attack.  Use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which type is your [Room Number] column? If it is a string then you have to write the value with inverted comma or quotation mark (I'm not sure which of both is used in Access).

```
string sql = " DELETE FROM HotelCustomers WHERE [Room Number] = '" +  textBox1.Text + "'";
```

To avoid SQL injektion you should use Parameters instead of the string operation.

Answer (score 3):

Use parametrized query to avoid all kind of errors

```
   string sql = " DELETE FROM HotelCustomers WHERE [Room Number] =?";
   using(OleDbConnection My_Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= c:\\Users\\Documents\\HotelCustomersOld.mdb"))
   {
        My_Connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand My_Command = new OleDbCommand(sql, My_Connection);
        My_Command.Parameters.Add("@p1",  textBox1.Text);
        My_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

In your case the Room NUmber field is of Text type so, you need to enclose the value in single quotes, but this is really wrong. You expose your code to maliciuos  text written by your user inside the text box. A very simple and [funny example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void DeleteLine(string kv)
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
    string myQuery = "DELETE FROM Cloth WHERE [ClothName] = '" + kv + "'";
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source = E:\\Sohkidatabase\\Sohki.accdb");
        con.Open();
        str = "select * from compny_info where id=" + comboBox1.Text.Trim() + "";
        com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
        OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = reader["regis_no"].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = reader["comp_oner"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = reader["comp_name"].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = reader["comp_add"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = reader["tin_no"].ToString();
                textBox6.Text = reader["email"].ToString();
             }

            con.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static void DeleteLine(string kv) {
      OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
      string myQuery = "DELETE FROM Cloth WHERE [ClothName] = '" + kv + "'" ;
 }
```

Comment: Did you mean this to be an edit to your [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29487991/519348)?